# Framing error on Rx line in rs485 to ethernet converter

Tags: hardware, converter, rs485

I have a device connected to MOXA nPort 5150 via 4-wire rs-485 cable. Termination resistor inside the converter was set to 1 kΩ (another option was 150 kΩ, which didn't work at all - I got framing errors on both sides) and now I have a correct signal on transmitting lines (my device properly reacts to commands).

Unfortunately, the data that is sent back from the device to converter is corrupted. I constantly get framing errors with parts of data intact. For example I shoud get 18 bytes of data:

30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 0d 00

And I get 17:

30 60 30 30 30 30 30 31 04 02 82 02 06 02 02 82 0d 00

Incorrect serial port settings obviously aren't the reason (as I can transmit data to the device correctly). It is also highly unlikely that there is something wrong with the cable (I was able to connect another converter using the same cable and it worked, it was ATC1000 rs485 to ethernet converter).

Also, when I connect Rx lines to Tx lines (in a loop) the signal is passing through without problem.

I considered adding bias resistors to receive lines. I'll try it and see what happens aanyway, but it'll take some time. Meanwhile I wanted to ask:

**Is it possible that ATC1000  converter has bias resistors implemented internally, and MOXA5150 doesn't,  or rather MOXA has it implemented only on transmitting lines? Or can there be another reason for this problem?**

**EDIT:**

After adding bias resistor on receive line, signal is a little better (less framing errors), but is still corrupted.

Using shielded cable doesn't change anything.

Surprisingly, another MOXA device, UPort 1150 (which has bias resistors embedded) behaves in the exact same way (Transmision gets through without problems, receive signal is corrupted). This converter works correctly in other cases (with different devices). The third converter I have (ATC1000, not MOXA) still works correctly with my device...

Comment: It's probably not your only problem, but one potential issue can be the converter not going into receive mode fast enough to catch the reply - you can try introducing a delay in your device firmware.  As for the analog issues, it would be interesting if you can successfully communicate between two of these converters over the same cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I forgot that I even asked this question because I have never figured out the exact answer, just a workaround. I'm posting this now, maybe it'll help someone.

It turns out, the Moxa converter I was using at the time incorrectly interpreted signals from some devices and could not reliably differentiate between mark, space and iddle states while my other converter was able to do so. The issue seems to be specific to RS-485 Moxa converters, as the same thing happend a while later when a colegue of mine was trying to connect some other RS-485 device using Moxa (also, we tried different Moxa models, same thing kept happening). It is not all that widespread as I was able to find maybe two instances of people reporting this on the net. From my experience, it works OK most of the time, but then there are some devices that get this issue when other RS-485 converters work with them and Moxa doesn't. We figured it was a firmware issue with signal interpretation on the side of Moxa converter (or on the device side, which either way I couldn't address since I can't modify either). It was a while ago and as of this day, I don't know if Moxa addressed it or not.

For me it was simpler, faster and cheaper to just use a workaround. I bought a cheap RS-485 to RS-232 converter and inserted it between my device and Moxa, then changed the conversion mode on Moxa to RS-232. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

What resistor do you refer as the termination? The 1 kOhm resistor is still way to much for RS485. If the twisted pair is your media (as it should be), resistors should be around 120 Ohms (100 to 150 Ohms) between the lines. Of course, this should be arranged only at the connection endpoints. Is it possible that your ATC1000 which is working just have those resistors, and in other case they are not present (and you 1 kOhm is not a proper termination).

You migh also want to try some 10 kOhm resistors from each line to the ground. It is not termination, but helps keeping the noise on the lines down when there is no transmission (so that receivers would not get false signal triggering UARTs).

I have also had the case of going 'too fast' into reception mode (when working in half duplex), so that my firmware would cut off part of the message. It was resolved by having receiver on all the time so that my sender would actually 'see' everything that went down the line when transmitting. If that was not the case I would have to arrange for some delay before starting receiving, and delay could be to long so I could miss the start of the message.